# How to forward page to different file using mod_rewrite

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to user mod_rewrite to forward user from default `index.html` to `default.php`, I've tried using:

`Redirect 301 /index.html /default.php` in `/html/.htaccess`

but it adds default.php repeatedly until it fails:

```
http://localhost/default.phpdefault.phpdefault.phpdefault.phpdefault.phpdefault.phpdefault.phpdefault.phpdefault.phpdefault.phpdefault.phpdefault.phpdefault.phpdefault.phpdefault.phpdefault.phpdefault.phpdefault.phpdefault.phpdefault.phpdefault.php
```

---

EDIT:

I figured it out, there shouldn't be a 301 and I need to use the full URL as below:

`Redirect /index.html http://localhost/default.php`

Just need to know how to specify a variable that gives me the `http(s)://servername` bit

Comment: What other mod_alias / mod_rewrite directives do you have? Server config and/or .htaccess? This looks like a conflict with existing directives. Or possibly a caching issue?

Comment: "there shouldn't be a 301" - The presence of "301" in this instance makes no difference. Without it, a 302 is implied. "I need to use the full URL" - again, on Apache 2.4, this really should not make any difference. If you don't "use the full URL", the scheme and hostname from the current request is implicitly added. "specify a variable that gives me" - or are you suggesting that the scheme/host is variable and _different_ to the current request?

Comment: You're correct, double-checked and 301/302 can be present.  I did however try /index.html /default.php which did NOT work.  Only when I added http://localhost/ was it ok.  Just don't know how to automatically add the servername.

Comment: In your edit you state that this is in an `.htaccess` file located in the `/html` subdirectory. Is that the directory of your `localhost` document root? Also, as mentioned above, do you have any other directives in this file (or server config)?

Comment: It is the serving root, yes and there are no other directives in this file.

Answer (score 0):

> Just don't know how to automatically add the servername

You shouldn't *need* to. In fact, you can't "automatically" add the *servername* using a mod_alias `Redirect` directive. It is always *safer* to include a hardcoded absolute URL for the target, however, a root-relative URL should still work OK on a single canonical host - which appears to be the case here. (?) If it does not work, then it perhaps suggests some other server misconfiguration?

Alternatively, you could try a mod_rewrite (if enabled) redirect (using the `RewriteRule` directive). This does provide variables for the servername, although again, this should not be necessary.

Just to note that you should not mix mod_alias and mod_rewrite redirects. Mixing directives can result in unexpected conflicts - since the two modules run at different times, regardless of their apparent order.

Try the following mod_rewrite redirect in .htaccess, instead of the `Redirect` in your question.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.html /default.php [R=302,L]
```

To specifically use "variables" in the `RewriteRule` substitution:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.html http://%{SERVER_NAME}/default.php [R=302,L]
```

Note that this should come after any canonical redirect.

Instead of `SERVER_NAME`, you can use `HTTP_HOST` to refer to the hostname used in the request. Although, depending on your server config, these probably refer to the same thing (ie. the hostname used in the request).

This obviously hard codes the protocol eg. `http` (or `https`). Do you really have mixed protocol requests? (This should ideally be canonicalized earlier in the request.)

This is also a `302` (temporary) redirect. Change it to a `301` when you are sure it's working - if that is required. Temporary redirects are easier for testing since they are not cached by the browser.

---

Aside: This redirect does look a bit "suspect". Ordinarily, you wouldn't necessarily expect `index.html` or `default.php` to be part of the visible URL. Instead, Apache (using the `DirectoryIndex` directive of mod_dir) can automatically serve (via an internal rewrite) the appropriate `DirectoryIndex` document when the parent directory (ending in a slash) is request. So, you can change the `DirectoryIndex` document:

```
DirectoryIndex disabled
DirectoryIndex default.php
```

This will look for `default.php` (only) in whatever directory is requested. The `disabled` line is necessary in order to *remove* the previous document, since additional documents are normally appended to the list, which might not ne desirable if the old document (`index.html`) still exists.